# Remote Debuggging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to remotely debug C#.NET application installed on the client's windows 7/XP (not server) without any success. 
I tried to remotely debug on windows service and it works fine. 
One of the prerequisites is that "The remote device and the Visual Studio computer must be connected over a network or connected directly through an Ethernet cable. Debugging over the internet is not supported."
There is no network or an Ethernet cable between my pc and server, but it works, why it doesn't work on the client's pc with windows 7/XP? And is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Until Visual Studio 2013 (and perhaps 2012) it was very important to have the same account (with same password) on both machines. Visual studio had to run under this account and remote debugger also had to run under this account.

The problem was bigger when one of the computers was in a domain and one was not. Then the best thing was to create non-domain accounts on both computers and use these for remote debugging. And of course these accounts should have administrator rights to be safe.

Visual studio 2013 is different. It does not matter what user it runs under and it does not matter what user the remote debugger runs under. Upon connecting to remote debugger a credentials window is shown and you can input the right user name and password (that exists on the remote computer).

One important thing to note is that you should use corresponding version of remote debugger (i.e. from visual studio 2010 when you are debugging in vs2010). And there has to be a network connectivity. It is not important to be on the same network but you have to have network connectivity to the remote computer. Also consider disabling (or modifying) the firewall on the remote computer to be sure that no one is blocking access to the port remote debugger is using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to my question, I am using vs 2010 with the same version remote debugger vs2010. For now I am trying to solve the issue by using TeamViewer with creating of VPN on both machines and to run the remote debugging over it.

Comment: More info on doing it with newer VS versions, across the internet is available in my blog post https://keyoti.com/blog/remote-debug-net-applications-over-the-internet-with-visual-studio/